# Работа с input/placeholder

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Изобретаю велосипед (анимированный placeholder).
Никак не могу понять, как сохранить начальное значение value, чтобы оно выскакивало как при пустом input'e так и при заполненном. Делал чуть иначе, при этом новое значение введенное в input выскакивало вместо нужного (E-mail, Phone). Как это исправить? Да, важно использовать именно value, а не placeholder, т.к. нужно поддержка IE8.

Знаю, что уже есть решения на jQuery, но хочется своего велосипеда).

```js
(function animatePlaceholder() {

  var input = document.querySelectorAll('.input-box input[type="text"]');

  [].forEach.call(input, function(elem) {

    var span = document.createElement('span'),
      value;

    elem.onfocus = function() {

      value = this.value;
      span.innerHTML = value;

      this.parentNode.insertBefore(span, this);
      this.value = '';

      span.classList.add('placeholder');
      span.classList.add('placeholder-show');
    }

    elem.onblur = function() {
      span.classList.remove('placeholder-show');
      this.value = value;
    }
  });

}());
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.input-box {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 15px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.input-box input[type="text"] {
  height: 25px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: silver;
}
input[type="text"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.placeholder {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 5px;
  transition-duration: .5s;
  z-index: -100;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: silver;
}
.placeholder-show {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  z-index: 100;
  color: silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-box">
  <input type="text" value="E-mail" />
</div>

<div class="input-box">
  <input type="text" value="Phone" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать использовать `data-*`. `IE` вроде как не дружит с `.dataset`, однако `getAttribute` вполне подойдет.

Вместо `value` засовывать в `span` значение `data-аттрибута`, а очищать `value` только если оно имеет первоначальный вид.

```js
(function animatePlaceholder() {
  var input = document.querySelectorAll('.input-box input[type="text"]');
  [].forEach.call(input, function(elem) {
    var span = document.createElement('span'),
      value;
    elem.onfocus = function() {
      value = this.getAttribute('data-value');
      span.innerHTML = value;
      this.parentNode.insertBefore(span, this);
      if (this.value == "E-mail" || this.value == "Phone") this.value = '';
      span.classList.add('placeholder');
      span.classList.add('placeholder-show');
    }
    elem.onblur = function() {
      span.classList.remove('placeholder-show');
      if(this.value == "") this.value = this.getAttribute('data-value'); 
    }
  });
}());
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.input-box {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 15px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.input-box input[type="text"] {
  height: 25px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: silver;
}
input[type="text"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.placeholder {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 5px;
  transition-duration: .5s;
  z-index: -100;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: silver;
}
.placeholder-show {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  z-index: 100;
  color: silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-box">
  <input type="text" value="E-mail" data-value="E-mail" />
</div>

<div class="input-box">
  <input type="text" value="Phone" data-value="Phone" />
</div>
```

Comment: Немного подкорректировал Ваше решение - вместо if (this.value == "E-mail" || this.value == "Phone") сделал if (this.value == this.getAttribute('data-value')) Так на мой взгляд лучше дабы не переписывать все значения data-value в условии

Comment: А в остальном спасибо)). Тоже вчера перед сном это решение пришло в голову))

Comment: согласен, лучше конечно сравнивать с `data-*`,